# Form sends request despite form not filled

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

Hi friends I have a form which have inputs, textboxes and selects in Angular. I use devexpress theme. Despite form not filled it sends request when submitting. I used dx-validation and "required" it does not worked. Help me please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly share some code, and try to describe the issue

Comment: Please provide stackblitz reproduction so we can help you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/